# Array with single attribute of many-to-many Eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I created a model `NearMiss` that has a many-to-many relationship with a `Type` model. When there is a GET request for a specific `NearMiss`, I want an array to be attached to the JSON output that has the `name` attribute of all `Type` instances that belong to the `NearMiss` instance.

I can attach an array of Types to the output, but I want to get rid of all the additional information (such as pivot information).

The GET request `/nearmisses/{nearmiss}` executes the following method:

```
public function show($id) 
    {
        try {
            $nearmiss = NearMiss::findOrFail($id)->first();
            $nearmiss->types->makeHidden(['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);
            return response()->json($nearmiss);
        } catch(ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            abort(400, 'Model not found');
        }
    }
```

The `NearMiss` model has the following types relation:

```
public function types() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Type', 'near_miss_type', 'near_miss_id', 'type_id');
    }
```

Current output:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "location_long": "0.0000000",
    "location_lat": "0.0000000",
    "employee_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-02-11 16:38:24",
    "updated_at": "2019-02-11 16:38:24",
    "types": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Brandgevaar"
            "created_at": "2019-02-11 16:33:25",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-11 16:33:25",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Slipgevaar",
            "created_at": "2019-02-11 16:34:12",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-11 16:34:12",
        }
    ]
}
```

I know that I can remove additional attributes (such as id, created_at, updated_at), but that still leaves me with an array of `Type` instances (with just a single name attribute). When I try `flatten()` I receive an error that `flatten()` can't be used on BelongsToMany relationships.

Desired output:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "location_long": "0.0000000",
    "location_lat": "0.0000000",
    "employee_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-02-11 16:38:24",
    "updated_at": "2019-02-11 16:38:24",
    "types": [
        "Brandgevaar", "Slipgevaar"
    ]
}
```

Can someone help me to get the desired output please.

Comment: Can you show the query you are currently using to generate this output?

Comment: I edited my original post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the types manually and use the [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_pluck) function to only get the name of each type.

```
$nearmiss->types = $nearmiss->types()->pluck('name');
```

However I'm not sure if this will interfere with the magic properties from Eloquent.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I already tried `pluck('name')` but without loading the types manually. Just calling `$nearmiss->types()->pluck('name')` (without assigning it to `$nearmiss->types`) doesn't work.

Comment: When calling the function without assigning, it just loads the data but does not store it anywhere.

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this as the answer to your question so other users might find this as well.